# border for navigation bar active class text only

Tags: html, css

in this image active class of "interview experience" will displayed as tab like "Questions".
[image]

```
<li class="active">
<a href="ras.php"><i class="fa fa-hourglass-end" ></i>Interview Experiences</a>
</li>
```

i want the border only for an text as like questions tab.
css design is

```
.active
{
 background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.active` class as below

```
.active a {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: in this the border takes full width@pugazh

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want it purely around the link - simply style the link itself. I assume you want it when hovering? If not, just delete`:hover`.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="border">
```

CSS:

```
a.border:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of assigning background like

```
.active
{
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

set it's border and target "a", set padding as per your requirement.

```
.active a
{
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
}
```